# Как установить минимальный размер шрифта на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день.

На сайте в `body` стоит `font-size: 0.8vw;`.

Как задать ещё минимальный размер шрифта, который разрешено применять? А то на широкий экранах шрифт получается маленьким.

Comment: Попробуйте задать шрифт начиная с определенной ширины `@media (min-width: 2900px) { body{font-size: 20px; } }`, где 2900px ширина с которой будет действителен новый размер шрифта.

Comment: да, это решение! Спасибо.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk Это вполне достойный ответ. Рекомендую перенести из комментариев в ответ (только без "попробуйте")

Answer (score 4):

Задайте шрифт начиная с определенной ширины `@media (min-width: 2900px) { body{font-size: 20px; } }`, где 2900px ширина с которой будет действителен новый размер шрифта.